# Why are interfaces in Java defined with a lowercase "i" (interface) rather than uppercase "I" (Interface)?

Tags: java, class, oop, generics, interface

When defining an interface,

why is

```
public interface Sample {
  public static final int K = 2;
  public abstract int num();
}
```

used instead of

```
public Interface Sample {
  public static final int K = 2;
  public abstract int num();
}
```

Is there any difference between the two or is it merely a styling convention?

Comment: All Java keywords are lowercase.

Comment: The second one is a syntax error. Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: for the same reason why `public`, `abstract`, `class` and other keywords were defined lowercase

Comment: Even the keyword `instanceof`, which arguably would have been more readable in camel case, `instanceOf`, must be written with all lowercase letters. And `interface` is a keyword too, so follows the rule.

Comment: Sooo... usually *downvoters* are asked why they downvoted. In this case, I'm rather curious where the upvotes come from...

Comment: Generally, languages define their grammar/syntax and it tells you in the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good comparison point would be to look at how Java handles classes. You'd write

```
public class MyClass {
   ...
}
```

rather than

```
public Class MyClass {
   ...
}
```

More generally, all Java reserved words are lower case. That's the convention, probably based on the conventions from C, C++, and the like.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a styling, that's the language Syntax

The second one won't work as that looks like you have another Class/Interface that's called Interface.